# ERROR: Plugin 'LoggerPlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. in iPhone 4s

Tags: ios7, ibm-mobilefirst, iphone-4

I am using:
Worklight V6.2.0.0
IOS 7.1
iPhone 4s

The application is running fine in iPhone5s but when installing the same app in the iPhone 4s I am getting the following error.

Could anyone let me know what exactly is causing the issue. As fas as I understand, it is saying "LoggerPlugin" not found. If it is so then how could I verify the presence for the same. If I remove it from the config.xml then I get the same error for different plugin. How do I resolve the issue?

```
ERROR: Plugin 'LoggerPlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2014-08-06 19:09:08.804 xxxxx[350:60b] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 158] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "INVALID",
  "LoggerPlugin",
  "log",
  [
    "DEBUG",
    "",
    "added onPause event handler ",
    {
      "$arguments" : [
        "added onPause event handler "
      ],
      "$src" : "js"
    },
    1407332348664
  ]
]
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget>
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value=".25" />
    <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="false" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
    <preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="false" />
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
    <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
    <preference name="GapBetweenPages" value="0" />
    <preference name="PageLength" value="0" />
    <preference name="PaginationBreakingMode" value="page" />
    <preference name="PaginationMode" value="unpaginated" />
    <preference name="EnableLocation" value="false" /><!-- DEPRECATED -->
    <preference name="UIControls" value='{"TabBarSettings": {"position": "bottom", "height": 49}, "ToolBarSettings": {"style": "Default"}}'/>

    <feature name="LocalStorage">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Battery">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVBattery" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Console">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Contacts">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVContacts" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Accelerometer">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVAccelerometer" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Compass">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCompass" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVNotification" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Globalization">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVGlobalization" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Media">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSound" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Capture">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCapture" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVConnection" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Vibration">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVVibration" />
    </feature>

    <!--worklight-->
    <feature name="WLSplashScreen">
        <param name="ios-package" value="WLSplashPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="LoggerPlugin">
        <param name="ios-package" value="LoggerPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="DeviceAuth">
        <param name="ios-package" value="DeviceAuthPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="UserAuth">
        <param name="ios-package" value="UserAuthPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="WebResourcesDownloader">
        <param name="ios-package" value="WebResourcesDownloader" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="WLDirectUpdatePlugin">
        <param name="ios-package" value="WLDirectUpdatePlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="WLNotification">
        <param name="ios-package" value="WLNotification" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="WLApp">
        <param name="ios-package" value="WLApp" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="UIControls">
        <param name="ios-package" value="UIControls" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Push">
        <param name="ios-package" value="Push" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="NetworkDetector">
        <param name="ios-package" value="NetworkDetector" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="NativePage">
        <param name="ios-package" value="NativePage" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="SecurityPlugin">
        <param name="ios-package" value="SecurityPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="StoragePlugin">
        <param name="ios-package" value="StoragePlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FIPSHttpPlugin">
        <param name="ios-package" value="FIPSHttpPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Badge">
        <param name="ios-package" value="Badge" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="NotificationEx">
        <param name="ios-package" value="NotificationEx" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="WifiPlugin">
        <param name="ios-package" value="WifiPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="CoreLocationGetLocationPlugin">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CoreLocationGetLocationPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="CoreLocationWatchPlugin">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CoreLocationWatchPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="SignificantChangeWatchPlugin">
        <param name="ios-package" value="SignificantChangeWatchPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="SignificantChangeGetLocationPlugin">
        <param name="ios-package" value="SignificantChangeGetLocationPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="WLNativeXHRPlugin">
        <param name="ios-package" value="WLNativeXHRPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="WLActionSenderPlugin">
        <param name="ios-package" value="WLActionSenderPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="WLTrusteer">
        <param name="ios-package" value="WLTrusteerPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Can you share your sample project on dropbox or something similar so that I can look into it. You could also provide your config.xml

Comment: You might want to try removing your iPhone environment from the Worklight project and recreating it

Answer (score 1):

First, try to first upgrade the Studio installation to the latest available by downloading the latest Worklight 6.2.0.1 iFix from IBM Fix Central.

Next, possible solutions:

1. Delete the iPhone environment folder and re-add it
2. Delete only the iphone\native folder and re-build the project

Follow either option with a re-run in Xcode.